# Template can't accept an object as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

How come that the following code is wrong? Which type of parameters does a template accept?

```
class MyClass
{
    int var;
};

template <MyClass a> struct s
{

};

int main()
{
    MyClass var;
    struct s<var>;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Template arguments have to be compile-time constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-type template parameters are constrained, not everything can be used. In particular, they must be compile-time constants, which is not your case. Concerning your template *definition*:

```
template <MyClass a> struct s
//        ^^^^^^^
{
};
```

See Paragraph 14.1/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> A non-type template-parameter **shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types**:
>
> — integral or enumeration type,
>
> — pointer to object or pointer to function,
>
> — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
>
> — pointer to member,
>
> — std::nullptr_t.

As you can see, user-defined types are not allowed. Concerning your template's *instantiation*, then:

```
struct s<var>;
//       ^^^ You most likely meant something like s<var> obj, but nevermind
```

See Paragraph 14.3.2/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter **shall be one of**:
>
> — for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression
>   (5.19) of the type of the template-parameter; or
>
> — the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
>
> — a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and
>   external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates
>   and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as
>   & id-expression, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall
>   be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
>
> — a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1.